# Есть список, там строки и числа, как мне убрать числа, с помощью filter()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = [1,'2',3,'4',5,'6',7,'89']

z = list( filter( a.digits, a ) )
```

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: @Viktorov вот как отсеяться все числа с помощью filter()

Comment: Я прочитал вопрос. А что у вас не получается то?

Comment: @Viktorov как отсеять числа с помощью filter() ?

Comment: Кажется, у нас сложилось непонимание. Если вы будете повторять одни и те же слова, я не смогу вам помочь. Почему вы думаете, что ваш код должен был бы работать? Что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать этим кодом? Или просто [почитайте сами](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html)

Comment: @Viktorov не могу отсеять, a.digits не работает

Comment: Я понимаю, что не работает. А что такое `a.digits` и почему оно должно было сработать то?

Comment: @Viktorov да понимаю что она не будет работать, как мне так сделать что бы работало, что нужно вписать в первый аргумент filter?

Comment: туда нужно вписать функцию. Я вам чуть выше ссылку дал, там с примерами написано

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было бы неплохо почитать документацию на функцию `filter`, а не пытаться угадывать её методы

```
a = [1,'2',3,'4',5,'6',7,'89']
z = list(filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, int), a))
print(z)
# ['2', '4', '6', '89']
```

Comment: я тут стараюсь, пытаюсь подтолкнуть человека к тому, чтобы разобраться, а не копировать бездумно код, а вы ...

Comment: @Viktorov :)) спасибо, просто хотел понять есть ли методы, а не функции, типа как filter(None, a)  здесь он убирает пустые строки, ну типа того